# Typescript NestJS get componets in modules

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I am using [NestJs](https://nestjs.com) for my application, I have defined some components and all is good.

I am stuck at one place I have a pure object in typescript which is not a Nest JS component, I need to access some value from database inside this object. I cannot make this as Nest js component and inject the repository, I need a way to get access to the Nest js bean some how.

In Java using Spring framework, I can do something like **applicationContext.getBean("")** it will get me the instance, **can I do something like this in NestJs.**

Answer (score 3):

Since `4.5.0` it's possible to grab any component instance directly from the `INestApplication` using `get()` method. The `select()` and `get()` method works equivalently as here https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/e2e-testing (scroll down to the table).